# How to convert a folder into a python package in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am unable to access the functions from a python package even when it contains the **init**.py file.

```
import __init__
```

This statement executes perfectly.

```
from  mrcnn import utils
```

The statement gives error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mrcnn'
```

Comment: You need a `__init__.py` not `init.py`. Take a look at [packaging documentation](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)

Comment: @SBylemans i think it actually is `__init__.py`, it's just formatting issue that it's shown in bold.